# Search Across Multiple Farms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

We have multiple SharePoint 2016 on-premises farms (all joined to the same domain), is there is a way to deploy a central search farm to search across all these SharePoint farms? if this is possible, can someone please refer some technical articles talking about this subject?

Answer (score 0):

For Good Answer: [Configure trust for search between two SharePoint Server 2013 farms](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dn133749.aspx)

Reference for Search Result configuration: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/11/04/how-to-configure-the-search-results-web-part-to-use-a-new-result-source-in-sharepoint-2013/